# Positioning the beginning of table of content (toc) to the top of the page

Tags: spacing, sectioning, table-of-contents, titlesec, tocloft

I managed with great help from here to shift the beginning of the chapter titles to the top of the page, but it doesn't affect the table of content. Why is that? And how could I do that?

I don't know, if everything is relevant... I tried to post a minimal version:

```
    \documentclass[paper=15cm:23cm, headinclude=true, numbers=enddot]{scrbook}
    \usepackage[automark]{scrpage2}   
    \usepackage{tocloft}
    \usepackage{titlesec}

    %%Position of chapter title
    \titleformat{\chapter}
                {\usekomafont{disposition}\usekomafont{chapter}}
                {\thechapter.\hspace{1em}}
                {0pt}
                {}
    \titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{-50pt}{15pt}    
    \areaset[10mm]{111mm}{195mm}

    \begin{document}
    \tableofcontents

    \chapter{Einleitung}

    \noindent Text Text DADA oooooooooText Text DADA oooooo ooo Text Text DADA ooooooooo Text DADA ooo  oooooo Text Text DADA ooooooooo Text DADA ooooo oooo Text Text DADA ooo oooooo Text DADA ooooo oooo Text Text DADA ooooooooo Text DADA oooo ooooo Text Text DADA oo ooooooo 

    \chapter{Second}

\noindent Text Text DADA oo ooooooo  Text Text DADA oooooooooText Text DADA oooooooooText Text DADA oooooooooText Text DADA ooo ooooooText Text DADA oo oooooooText Text DADA ooooooooo Text Text DADA ooooo oooo Text  Text DADA ooooooooo 

\section{Section}
Text Text DADA oooooooooText Text DADA oooooo ooo Text Text DADA ooooooooo Text DADA ooo  oooooo Text Text DADA ooooooooo Text DADA ooooo oooo Text Text DADA ooo oooooo Text DADA ooooo oooo Text Text DADA ooooooooo Text DADA oooo ooooo Text Text DADA oo ooooooo 

\subsection{SubSection}
Text Text DADA oooooooooText Text DADA oooooo ooo Text Text DADA ooooooooo Text DADA ooo  oooooo Text Text DADA ooooooooo Text DADA ooooo oooo Text Text DADA ooo oooooo Text DADA ooooo oooo Text Text DADA ooooooooo Text DADA oooo ooooo Text Text DADA oo ooooooo 

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a matter of calling

```
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
```

With this (weirdly named) option, the `tocloft` package won't intervene in the definitions of the headers for the Table of contents and Lists of ….

Comment: Doesn't work for me.

Comment: Where do I need to put it?

Comment: @lockstep Fixed

Comment: The class interacts correctly with `titlesec` -- `tocloft` is the culprit.

Comment: @lockstep Yes, and there's an option to neutralize the effect.

Comment: Indeed -- this is better than my solution.