# topline of fancyhdr disappears when I use tocloft

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr, tocloft

I have the problem that when I use package `tocloft` the line under the `fancyheader` disappears. It only disappears on pages with lists, like table of contents or list of figures. I would like to have this line on all pages. I guess the problem is somewhere within `tocloft` and `fancyhdr`. Because if I comment `tocloft` out, the line appears on top of the table of contents.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,fontsize=12pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}
\setlength{\parskip}\bigskipamount

\usepackage{tocloft}
\newcommand{\listappendicesname}{Appendices}
\newlistof{appendices}{apc}{\listappendicesname}
\newcommand{\appendices}[1]{\addcontentsline{apc}{appendices}{#1}}

\newcommand{\newappendix}[1]{\section*{#1}\appendices{#1}}

\pdfinfo{
  /Title    ()
  /Author   ()
  /Creator  ()
  /Producer ()
  /Subject  ()
  /Keywords ()
}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[head=36pt]{geometry} 

\fancyhf{}  
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\pagestyle{fancyplain}  

%\fancyhead[L]{\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{picture}}
\fancyhead[R]{\nouppercase{\leftmark}}
\fancyfoot[L]{Name}
\fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{bla1}
\section{bla2}
\section{bla3}

some text some text some text some text some text \\

\appendix
\listofappendices
\newpage

\newappendix{Appendix one} appendix  appendix appendix appendix appendix appendix
\newappendix{Appendix two} appendix  appendix appendix appendix appendix appendix
\newappendix{Appendix three} appendix  appendix appendix appendix appendix appendix
\newappendix{Appendix four} appendix  appendix appendix appendix appendix appendix

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) First of all try `\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a problem similar to [Positioning the beginning of table of content (toc) to the top of the page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51899/positioning-the-beginning-of-table-of-content-toc-to-the-top-of-the-page)

It's solved by calling the package as

```
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
```

> With this (weirdly named) option, the tocloft package won't intervene in the definitions of the headers for the Table of contents and Lists of ….