# Align Acronyms heading with TOC, LOF and LOT

Tags: acro

I am writing my dissertation and I am struggling to get the List of Abbreviations header to be aligned with the headers for the TOC, LOF, and LOT. I have looked around but could not find a suitable solution. I am using the acro package. I appreciate your help!

[image]

```
\documentclass[a5paper,twoside]{report}

\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{tocloft}

\usepackage{acro}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{
    \fancyhead{}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
}


\begin{document}

\clearpage

\pagenumbering{roman}

\pagestyle{plain}

\tableofcontents \markboth{Table of contents}{Table of contents}

\clearpage

\listoffigures \markboth{List of figures}{List of figures}

\clearpage

\listoftables \markboth{List of tables}{List of tables}

\clearpage

\acsetup{list/display=used,list/heading=chapter*}

\printacronyms[name=List of abbreviations] \markboth{List of abbreviations}{List of abbreviations}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! I guess you are using `\documentclass{book}` but that is a crucial detail which right now is missing...

Comment: Sorry! I left that out when copying the code. I have edited my question now. Actually I use `\documentclass{report}`.

Comment: This is specific to `tocloft` and can be seen with `\chapter*{Foo}` as well as `\printacronyms`, I think [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/51900/106162) resolves your problem?

Comment: Yes! Indeed it does, thank you very much!