# Adjusting top margin for List of Symbols and List of Acronyms using nomencl and glossaries packages

Tags: glossaries, nomencl

I am using the `nomencl` package for the List of Symbols and the `glossaries` package for the List of Acronyms in my LaTeX document. However, I'm facing difficulty adjusting the top margin specifically for these lists. I have set the top margin for the entire document to 1 inch using the `geometry` package, but it doesn't seem to affect the Lists of Symbols and Acronyms generated by `nomencl` and `glossaries` respectively. I have also tried modifying the `\nompreamble` command for `nomencl` and using the `\setlength{\glsdescwidth}` command for `glossaries`, but they haven't provided the desired results. How can I adjust the top margin for the Lists of Symbols and Acronyms while still using the `nomencl` and `glossaries` packages? Any suggestions or alternatives would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

I have made dirty workaround with

```
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype,title={\vspace{-3cm}\centering LIST OF ACRONYMS AND ABBREVIATIONS},nonumberlist]
```

Comment: Are you using `tocloft`?

Comment: yes, I am using `tocloft`

Comment: Try loading it with the `titles` package option (https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/51900/106162)

Comment: nomencl uses \chapter* (or \section* if needed) to print the title, which adds a 60pt gap above the title.  glossaries is more complicated, in fact I can't tell what the heck it is up to.  I couldn't even find a single use of \vspace or \vskip in the package.

Comment: @DaiBowen But it broke the pre- title spacing of lot, lof, and toc. How to solve???

Comment: @SushilKhatri I'm just speculating, I can't see what you can see both in code and output, and I'm not certain as to what you want.  If your question is different from the one linked then it will need a different answer, but without seeing how you're producing the various lists I have no further ideas.